# How to implement live-videostreaming within a-frame?

Tags: webrtc, aframe, live-streaming, 360-virtual-reality

I want to implement live 360 video using Theta s camera. I already have done implementation
using three.js for showing images in 360 and live audio stream using WEB RTC. 
I found implementation using a-frame for images and video but I couldn't find anything on how to implement using live stream in 360 from my camera input. My question
is how to get the input from my Theta s camera and to show in 360 perspective. 
My idea is to get the video from my camera input, to glue on a ball object and to be shown on full screen.